# Convert text to uppercase between tag keeping them

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to convert HTML content to uppercase using XSLT, but the requirement is to keep the tag hierarchy unaltered (i.e., just change the text).

For example: `<p>some text <b>other text</b></p>`
should result in
`<p>SOME TEXT <b>OTHER TEXT</b></p>`.

With the following XSLT I managed to convert the text to uppercase, but the result loses the tag hierarchy.

```xml
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" method="xhtml" standalone="0" version="1.0"/>

  <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(/, $smallcase, $uppercase)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Is there any way to keep the tags unaltered?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
  
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $smallcase, $uppercase)"/>
</xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that `xhtml` is not a valid output method in XSLT 1.0.